# Is "newcomers" an acceptable synonym for "new arrivals" in a country?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for advice from native speakers of English on the following question:

Is "newcomers" a possible and acceptable synonym for "new arrials" in the sense of people who have come just recently to a certain country, usually not for tourism or other sorts of temporary sojourns, rather for long-term accommodation (migrants, refugees, expats... however you want to call them).

Reason for the question: I have to write a lot about such people, and I want to use a neutral term perhaps semantically less unwieldy than"new arrivals", and easier to grasp for people who are not utterly fluent in English.<sup>1</sup>

I find "newcomer" listed even in some dictionaries with a meaning like that (e.g. as English word for German *Neuankömmling*), but I think I have never met it in use in, say, British or US American newspapers or scientific papers, so I am in doubt. My feeling is that *newcomer* relates to  low level of expertise in some form of activity, not to some actual spatial arrival.

A sample sentence would be

> In August 2018 we started a new project to offer literacy training for newcomers from Bulgaria.

Meaning: people who have come recently from Bulgaria to this country.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Newcomers to English, so to say.

Comment: I am a native English speaker and sometime resident of both Canada and the U.S.  I have frequently been a “newcomer” in a community, sometimes after a change in province, state or country. To my mind, “newcomer” is a more neutral term than “new arrival”. I don’t know how it would be in a small country like the U.K., where ideas of time and space are different from those of the New World.

Comment: @GlobalCharm  Thank you for that insight in real-life use-cases of *newcomer* etc. In your experience, what is the impression (look and feel, connotation) of *new arrival* then? Does it tend to carry something of "oh these annoying immigrants", or does it sound bureaucratic? (I suppose it is a bit bureaucratic, that's actually my first motivation for looking for an alternative...)

Comment: For people of a certain social class, or for anyone who has bettered their living conditions by moving, *arriviste* has a unique sting. Look at https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/arriviste and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parvenu A term like *new arrivals* would be felt as dismissive, even insulting.

Answer (score 2):

> Is “newcomers” an acceptable synonym for “new arrivals” in a country?

Yes!

a **newcomer**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126529?rskey=6aMAP8&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> A person who or thing which has newly come to a place, situation,
>   etc.; a new or recent arrival;

As in:

In August we started a new project offering literacy training for/to newcomers from Bulgaria.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. -  I find *newcomer* for somebody phyiscally arriving somwhere also in Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English, but, as I said, my doubts are there because I have never met that word in that (unmetaphorical) use anywhere. - Regarding the link to OED: this, unfortunately, is of limited use as it requires a subscription at costs of 90 dollars annually... :-(

Answer (score 1):

(Warning: I am not a native speaker)

I see no issue with using 'newcomer' to denote recent immigration. As you, I also associate the term with *activities*, but just as a job is a professional activity, I'd argue residence can be a form of societal activity.

Check out [BYU corpora](https://www.english-corpora.org/) for a bunch of useful corpus databases, maybe you'll come across 'newcomer' used in a related context.

Comment: Thanks for the BYU link. This will be very useful for me henceforth.